# Send cloud-init script to gcp with terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp, cloud-init

How do I send cloud-init script to a gcp instance using terraform?

[Documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/cloudinit/latest/docs/data-sources/cloudinit_config) is very sparse around this topic.

Answer (score 7):

You need the following:

### A cloud-init file (say 'conf.yaml')

```yaml
#cloud-config

# Create an empty file on the system
write_files:
- path: /root/CLOUD_INIT_WAS_HERE
```

### cloudinit_config data source

`gzip` and `base64_encode` must be set to `false` (they are `true` by default).

```
data "cloudinit_config" "conf" {
  gzip = false
  base64_encode = false

  part {
    content_type = "text/cloud-config"
    content = file("conf.yaml")
    filename = "conf.yaml"
  }
}
```

### A metadata section under the google_compute_instance resource

```
  metadata = {
    user-data = "${data.cloudinit_config.conf.rendered}"
  }
```